# How do I define my props the same as an "img" element in typescript with Vue?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'd like to have type inference for a component that pass all his props for a `img` element.

I tried this:

```
defineProps<ImgHTMLAttributes>()
// and
defineProps<HTMLImageElement>()
```

Both returns the error:

> [plugin:vite:vue] [@vue/compiler-sfc] Unresolvable type reference or unsupported built-in utility type

This is my component:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import type { ImgHTMLAttributes }  from 'vue'

defineProps<ImgHTMLAttributes>()
// or defineProps<HTMLImageElement>()


</script>

<template>
  <div>
    // Some other elements here
    <img
      v-bind="$attrs"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: defineProps is a macro and shouldn't use external types afaik.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure this is what u are asking for , but this is how u say u expect to receive a prop in a custom component :

```
interface Props {
  xxxxxx?: number;
}

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
  xxxxxx: undefined,
});
```

Comment: answer is not clear and if possible, provide sufficient supporting information

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your vue version is up to `3.3`. (https://github.com/vuejs/core/pull/8083)

Or you can try this:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import type { ImgHTMLAttributes }  from 'vue'

interface IProps extends ImgHTMLAttributes {

}

defineProps<IProps>()


</script>

<template>
  <div>
    // Some other elements here
    <img
      v-bind="$attrs"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```